# python: how to display a html table which has two unequal columns (want to put a scroll bar)

Tags: python, html, parsing, jupyter-notebook, jinja2

how to display a html table which has two unequal columns (want to put a scroll bar).

Example:

```
column1:          
1.pencil
2.color
3.brush

column2:
1.ball
2.bat 
3.wickets 
4.field
5.players 
6.coach
7.audience
```

How to display these two columns in a html table with headers art, cricket. Each column must have a scroll bar and the table size must be fixed. Is there any way to achieve this as an output in jupyter notebook. (input : Two lists.   output: html table with each list as a column with a scroll bar since the elements in the list are unequal).

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two tables inside a div and style it with CSS.
`

```
<html>   
<head>
    <style>
        #outer_div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        table {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        th {
            top:10px;
            position: fixed;
        }
        #arts_table {
            height: 100px;
        }
        #cricket_table {
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="outer_div">
        <table id="arts_table" class="common_table">
            <th>ARTS</th>
            <tr>
                <td>pencil</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>color</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>brush</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>paint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>paper</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>glue</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="cricket_table" class="common_table">
            <th>CRICKET</th>
            <tr>
                <td>ball</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>bat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>wickets</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>field</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>players</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>coach</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>audience</td>
            </tr>             
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: How to keep the headers fixed. These headers are scrolling along with the content.

Comment: Keep the header fixed by CSS style position : fixed.